# How do I merge my /boot partition to be a part of the / partition?

Tags: partitioning

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 under VirtualBox on a Windows server. When I first set up the machine I opted to put `/boot` on its own 230 MB partition. This turns out not to have been necessary for my situation and now I’d like to roll `/boot` into the much larger partition I use for `/`. How can I safely make this change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Long answer: If you insist on fixing what ain't broke:

1. Open a Terminal window.
2. Type `sudo mkdir /boot2`
3. Type `sudo cp -a /boot/* /boot2/`
4. Type `sudo umount /boot`
5. Type `sudo rmdir /boot`
6. Type `sudo mv /boot2 /boot`
7. Edit `/etc/fstab` and comment out the line that defines the mount point for `/boot`.
8. Type `sudo grub-install`
9. Type `sudo update-grub` (if you're using a BIOS-based install, you'll also need to specify a device filename -- probably `/dev/sda`)
10. Optionally delete the `/boot` partition and resize the root (`/`) partition. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) for details on how to do this.

***I have not tested this procedure!*** If I've forgotten something or if there's an unexpected error, your system will be rendered ***unbootable!*** Hence:

11. Please reconsider my "short answer," above.

Comment: It *is* broke: Ubuntu automatically installs new kernels but doesn’t automatically remove old ones, so `/boot` will run out of space every month or two unless someone manually uninstalls the old kernels. I will read through the documentation of these commands and gingerly give it a shot.

Comment: This worked for me. Though step 7 should be *comment out* instead of "uncomment", and I needed to specify the device name (in my case `/dev/sda`) in step 8.

Comment: @WangDingwei, I've edited the answer appropriately. Thanks for pointing out the error and omission.

Comment: Specifying the drive is probably related to `grub-install` instead of `update-grub`.

Comment: If this works out for `/boot` I suppose it should work for `/var` as well, right?

Comment: @RodSmith Unless I'm mistaken (and in spite of the clear mention that this procedure has not been tested), the `rmdir` command called in 7. would not work unless `/boot` is empty, right?

Perhaps recommending the use of [Trash management](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Trash_management) tools following the [FreeDesktop.org's Trash Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html) may help a bit in gaining confidence here. What do you think?

Comment: What about raspberry clones? I have an ODROID-HC2 headless with an sd card with 2 partitions: /boot has 400MBs and / has 1600MBs. Both are ext4. It will be great to merge them in one partition, but such devices do not have and do not boot with grub. Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

Updating with new answer that supports EFI. (EFI requires a FAT32 partition mounted as /boot/efi).

1. `sudo cp -a /boot /boot2`
2. `sudo umount /boot/efi && sudo umount /boot || echo -e "\n\rNot EFI?? STOP!"`
3. `sudo rmdir /boot`
4. `sudo cp -a /boot2 /boot`
5. `sudo rm -r /boot/efi/*`
6. `sudo mount /boot/efi`
7. `sudo diff -r /boot /boot2 && sudo rm -r /boot2 || echo -e "\n\r\n\rSOMETHING'S WRONG, STOP!!"`
8. `sudo nano /etc/fstab`

   - Edit /etc/fstab and comment out the line that defines the mount point for /boot. Leave the /boot/efi entry unaltered!
9. `sudo update-grub`

   - Make sure entries are found in /boot/, e.g. "Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-*"
10. Optionally, delete the /boot partition and resize the / partition.