# Not enough free disc space // unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg, dependencies

i'm stuck in a chain of errors.

Since a long time I regularly get the error that I dont have enough free disk space in boot. (I always managed to resolve the problem but not this time)

My current kernel version is

```
4.4.0-101-generic
```

I tried to remove other kernels using

```
sudo apt-get purge image-extra-4.4.0-xxx-generic
```

and get the error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic but it is not going to be installed
```

Now I'm stuck with this error and I can't find any other questions with a similar error.

What should I do?

My long term goal is to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04. to 16.06, but I feel like I have to resolve that issue first. Also,is there a way to completely resolve this problem? (Since it happened to me every 2 months or so.)

**Update**: Thanks for the quick answers so far!
Here is the output-->

```
ll /boot
total 231964
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Apr 24 23:17 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root     4096 Nov 30 17:01 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1249214 Nov 10 21:39 abi-4.4.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1246835 Aug  2  2017 abi-4.4.0-89-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1247269 Aug 14  2017 abi-4.4.0-93-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1249161 Sep 13  2017 abi-4.4.0-96-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1249112 Sep 20  2017 abi-4.4.0-97-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1249237 Okt 11  2017 abi-4.4.0-98-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190497 Nov 10 21:39 config-4.4.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190364 Aug  2  2017 config-4.4.0-89-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190364 Aug 14  2017 config-4.4.0-93-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190525 Sep 13  2017 config-4.4.0-96-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190525 Sep 20  2017 config-4.4.0-97-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190525 Okt 11  2017 config-4.4.0-98-generic
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     1024 Nov 30 17:02 grub/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 23170072 Dez  6 14:55 initrd.img-4.4.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 23074243 Dez  6 14:56 initrd.img-4.4.0-57-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 23091471 Dez  6 14:55 initrd.img-4.4.0-89-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 23090990 Dez  6 14:55 initrd.img-4.4.0-93-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 23171154 Dez  6 14:55 initrd.img-4.4.0-96-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 23170886 Dez  6 14:55 initrd.img-4.4.0-97-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 23170889 Dez  6 14:55 initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
drwx------  2 root root    12288 Jan 25  2016 lost+found/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   176500 Mär 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   178176 Mär 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   178680 Mär 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  3900892 Nov 10 21:39 System.map-4.4.0-101-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3898002 Aug  2  2017 System.map-4.4.0-89-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3899015 Aug 14  2017 System.map-4.4.0-93-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3899973 Sep 13  2017 System.map-4.4.0-96-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3899943 Sep 20  2017 System.map-4.4.0-97-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3900749 Okt 11  2017 System.map-4.4.0-98-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7006432 Nov 10 21:39 vmlinuz-4.4.0-101-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7000368 Aug  2  2017 vmlinuz-4.4.0-89-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7000752 Aug 14  2017 vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7003248 Sep 13  2017 vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7005136 Sep 20  2017 vmlinuz-4.4.0-97-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7006544 Okt 11  2017 vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
```

I followed the instructions in this Question [My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to) 
and managed to make room on boot (about 70%), but after I hit `sudo apt-get update` my terminal installed every image back and ran out of space before it could complete the installation of the critical images `103` and `121`, which have the unmet dependencies.

In addition, I tried to unmount my /boot partition and followed these Instructions [How do I merge my /boot partition to be a part of the / partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741672/how-do-i-merge-my-boot-partition-to-be-a-part-of-the-partition?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
I came so far as to comment out the part where the mount point of boot is defined. (I had to unmount a busy /boot though using `umount -l`)
But when I hit `sudo grub-install` I got the error

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

Comment: run `ll /boot` in your terminal and copy the output into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and it was caused by insufficient disk space on /boot (*No space left on device*).  I was able to resolve the problem with the following command to remove and purge the old kernels installed while keeping the current kernel:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l 'linux-image-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r| sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d')
```

This may not be a safe solution because it will keep the current kernel only while removing all other kernels. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to your problem is to get rid of the separate `/boot` partition and make it a sub-directory under `/` instead. There is no "official" answer on how to do this in **Ask Ubuntu** that I found but this Q&A answered by Rod Smith comes the closest: [How do I merge my /boot partition to be a part of the / partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741672/how-do-i-merge-my-boot-partition-to-be-a-part-of-the-partition?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Looking at your `ll /boot` output there are three kernels to quickly remove to get back space:

```
sudo rm -f /boot/*4.4.0-96*
sudo rm -f /boot/*4.4.0-97*
sudo rm -f /boot/*4.4.0-98*
```

Then you can fully remove them following these instructions (substituting `x` for valid number):

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x-x-generic
```

Now you should have enough space to install at least one new kernel, probably two.

After you get one or two new working kernels installed, you can use remove kernels `-83` and `-89` as well. From then on use:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and it will remove all kernels except the two latest versions.

Comment: i've added the output and also updated, what I tried in the meantime

Comment: @Arkantos I've updated instructions to get you going. Haven't found the answer to the `grub-install` problem under EFI yet though. You might want to post a comment under the answer in that thread. Ask if the OP can update answer for your error message.